# Issues with named POSIX semaphore

Tags: multithreading, posix, semaphore

I am trying to use POSIX named semaphore to ensure that only one instance of my executable can run. But I am running into trouble; the semaphore's value is always 0, so it always blocks.

```
#include <semaphore.h>  /* required for semaphores */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>     /* usleep */
#include <fcntl.h>      // O_EXCL
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* exit, EXIT_FAILURE */


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ret;
  int i;
  sem_t* semaphore;

  semaphore = sem_open("/mysemaphore", O_EXCL, 0777 /*0644*/, 2);
  printf("sem_open returned %p at line %u\n", semaphore, __LINE__);

  // if it exists, open with "open", and parameters will be ignored (therefore given as 0)
  if(!semaphore)
  {
    semaphore = sem_open("/mysemaphore", O_CREAT, 0, 0);
    printf("sem_open returned %p at line %u\n", semaphore, __LINE__);
  }

  // either of the above calls should have given us a valid semaphore
  assert(semaphore);

  // read its value time and again
  ret = sem_getvalue(semaphore, &i);
  printf("sem_getvalue returned %i at line %u, value is %i\n", ret, __LINE__, i);

// ....
```

Output:

```
sem_open returned 0x8003a4e0 at line 36
sem_getvalue returned 0 at line 50, value is 0
```

Platform: Cygwin 1.7.33-2

Built with this command:

```
gcc Main.c -o Main -lpthread
```

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The semaphore will start out with a value of 0. Do you have any code anywhere that actually increments (calls sem_post()) on your semaphore ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sem_post(semaphore)` to increase, `sem_wait(semaphore)` to decrease.

Also, when using O_CREAT, mode and value should be specified to something useful:

```
semaphore = sem_open("/mysemaphore", O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
```

Comment: Many thanks for replying to my request. However, I don't understand what you mean with "mode and value should be specified to something useful": I set value to 1 or 2, because that is what I want, but it appears to have no effect. What is the correct value for "value" and "mode"? What is the purpose of setting something for value, if the value is 0 anyway?

Comment: With respect to the above, according to sem_open() specification, "if O_CREAT is specified, and a semaphore with the given name already exists, then mode and value are ignored." (I copied this statement from [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html))

Comment: I can confirm that using sem_post() I can increase the value of the semaphore. It doesn't answer the questions above, but it allows me to move forward a bit. What I can see now is that when I do the following at the end of my program: 'code'(sem_close(semaphore);  sem_unlink("/mysemaphore");) and run the program again, the semaphore still exists, which is unexpected.